# What am I missing: Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the source, but it is

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Output of `bundle install`:

```
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.4) 
Using multi_json (1.7.8) 
Using activesupport (3.2.7) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.7) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.5) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.7) 
Using mime-types (1.23) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.14) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.7) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activerecord (3.2.7) 
Using activeresource (3.2.7) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (1.4.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (3.2.7) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using bundler (1.1.5) 
Using rails (3.2.7) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.6) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7) 
Using uglifier (2.1.2) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
MacBook:tickets michael$ 
MacBook:tickets michael$ rake db:migration
Could not find i18n-0.6.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And when do you get the error?

Answer (score 1):

Use `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried 
**bundle install** again. 
And then do rake db:migrate

Answer (score 0):

Try running `bundle exec bundle` (yes, `bundle` two times).